# Fragmente and Context

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, simplecursoradapter, android-context

I have this code into one **Fragment** but where ask for Context in the Fragment it does not work:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter ad1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(**What i put here**, R.layout.spinner, cursor, from, to);
```

if this code were into *Activity* it would be:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(**This**, R.layout.spinner, cursor, from, to);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getActivity()` to access the fragment's activity context:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter ad1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, cursor, from, to);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But  returns Null...the same way;

Comment: Probably don't want to use the application context in this case (since adapters usually handle view inflation). Just use `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SQLiteDatabase db =  getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("IbsPEC.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
          Spinner  ddlPrdutor1 = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ddlProdutor1);
          Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery("SELECT rowid _id,_grupo, id, nome FROM PRODUTOR ORDER BY NOME", null);

          String[] from = { "nome", "_id", "_grupo" }; 
          int[] to = { R.id.lblNome, R.id.lblId, R.id.lbl_id_FK };            

        SimpleCursorAdapter ad1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, cursor, from, to); 
        ad1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


          ddlPrdutor1.setAdapter(ad1);
          db.close();
```

*in debug mode, the error happen in :  ddProdutor1.setAdapter(ad1);
Return Exception NullPointer nothing more;   this class is a Fragment.*